# Linking transactions when using XMR.to to send bitcoins?

Tags: privacy, xmr.to

Since xmr.to is a xmr to btc converter. Does xmr.to use the same bitcoin address to send out?

I'm worried if the previous person that used the service to send bitcoins to a known dark web address and then in theory it could be linked back to me as I also used the same service with bitcoins coming from the same address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if XMR.TO uses the same address, but honestly it wouldn't matter. It would be relatively trivial to correlate all of XMR.TO's Bitcoin addresses.

Your more important concern regarding any links back to you is not something you should worry about.

When you connect to XMR.To, the only link to you is your IP address. If you connect to the site with Tor or I2P (as is recommended), then the site has no strong link to you.

The Bitcoin transactions you make with XMR.TO would look the same as the transactions from every other XMR.TO user. All transactions made from XMR.TO could be known as such, but that would not create any connections to the users of these services.